# How can I finish writing this program using a while loop?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

I'm having trouble finishing this program. I understand what the program is suppose to do, but I'm having trouble finishing it. I have my code posted below.

For this program I am required to determine if a number is a prime number. A part from this, I'm required to ask the user to enter a range (ex. 1-10) and display which numbers are prime and which are not.

This is what I have so far...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PrimeNumbers
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        //Create Scanner Object
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Initialize variable 
        double num1, range;


        //Prompt the user to enter in a number
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter in a number:");
            num1 = input.nextDouble();

            //Decision making
            if(num1 % 2 == 0 || num1 % 3 == 0 || num1 % 4 == 0 || num1 % 5 == 0 || num1 % 6 == 0 || num1 % 7 ==0 || num1 % 8 ==0 || num1 % 9 == 0)
            {
                //Display message
                System.out.println(num1 + " is not a prime number.");

                System.out.println("Please enter a range: ");
                range = input.nextInt();

                if ()
            }

            else
                //Display output
                System.out.println(num1 + " is prime.");

        }

        while(num1 == -1);
        {
            System.out.println("This program has now ended.");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You should check to see that num1 isn't equal to the number you're taking the modulo of.

Comment: What clever formatting! I was about to comment on the `;` after your `while`, but then I realized that the `while` line is the latter clause of a `do-while` and not a standalone `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

http://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/java-program-to-display-prime-numbers/

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class PrimeNumbers2
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {        
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      int i =0;
      int num =0;
      //Empty String
      String  primeNumbers = "";
      System.out.println("Enter the value of n:");
      int n = scanner.nextInt();
      for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)         
      {                   
         int counter=0;           
         for(num =i; num>=1; num--)
         {
        if(i%num==0)
        {
        counter = counter + 1;
        }
     }
     if (counter ==2)
     {
        //Appended the Prime number to the String
        primeNumbers = primeNumbers + i + " ";
     }  
      } 
      System.out.println("Prime numbers from 1 to n are :");
      System.out.println(primeNumbers);
   }
}
```